# Django: model foreign key and a selectbox widget

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-forms

I've 2 models `Worker` and `Position` when I add a new worker there should be selectbox with the positions listed in `Positions` model.

I tried to use `Select` widget but django fails with `no such property` exception.

**Models**

```
# Position model
class Position(models.Model):
    p_name   = models.CharField(max_length = 40, unique = True, verbose_name = 'Position')
    p_salary = models.IntegerField(max_length = 11, verbose_name = 'Salary')

    fields = ('p_name', 'p_salary')
```

```
# Worker model
class Worker(models.Model):
    w_name     = models.CharField(max_length = 40, verbose_name = 'Name')
    w_lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 40, verbose_name = 'Lastname')
    w_position = models.ForeignKey(to = Position, to_field = 'p_name', verbose_name = 'Position')
    w_dept     = models.ForeignKey(to = Department, to_field = 'd_name' verbose_name = 'Department')
```

**Form**

```
class WorkerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Worker

        widgets = {
            'w_name'    : TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'e name'}),
            'w_lastame' : TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'e lastname'}),
            'w_position': Select(attrs = {'class': 'e position'}),
            'w_dept'    : Select(attrs = {'class': 'e department'}),
        }
```

**Definition in admin.py**

```
class WorkerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = WorkerForm
```

`list_display = ('w_name', 'w_lastname', 'w_position', 'w_dept')`

What goes wrong how to make select box appear according to a foreign key?

Sultan

Comment: Is there any reason you can't show the actual error with the traceback? Why make us guess?

Comment: Can you provide a full traceback for any error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try just re-declaring the field for the form inside the form (making sure to use the same name as it is in the Model) and setting the widget and attrs in there?

Comment: Great! I just redeclared the field's widget inside the form and it worked. Thnaks)